# What do the symbols "=" and "==" mean in python? When is each used?

Tags: python

When should I write `==` in Python code, and when should it just say `=`? What does `==` actually mean?

Sometimes I get an error message when I try using `=` that goes away if I change it to `==`. It seems like `==` can be used in every situation. Is that true? If so, why is there a separate `=`, and why do I need to use the same symbol twice?

Comment: '=' is an assignment operator, '==' is a comparison operator.

Comment: Your textbook / tutorial should cover this very important information. Which book or tutorial are you using?

Comment: Questions this basic are better suited to a language tutorial.  You shouldn't be asking questions *that* basic here.

Comment: Surprisingly, when I tried to mark this as dupe, I couldn't find any dupe in SO.. did I miss any?

Comment: There's something to be said for languages that use `=` for equality and something else (`:=`, `←`, `≣`) for assignment. Those languages, however, are in the minority.

Answer (score 4):

`==` is a comparison operator while `=` will assign a value to said variable.

You can use `==` to see whether any two items as long they are the same type are equivalent:

```
if a == 2: # Compares whether a is equal to 2
    print a
```

Now here's the thing. If you  are comparing any two items like these, an error will pop up:

- String with integer
- Integer with string
- String and float
- Float and string

Floats and integers are comparable as they are numbers but are usually not equal to each other except when the float is basically the integer but with `.0` added to the end. When using `==`, if the two items are the same, it will return `True`. Otherwise, it will return `False`.

You can use `=` to assign values to variables. Using `==` will either do nothing or throw an error (if the variable is undefined). For example, you wanted the variable `hi` to have the value of 2. Then use the `=`:

```
hi = 2
```

Now `hi` is equal to 2. You can combine `=` with operations like `+` and `-` assuming the variable is an integer or float:

```
hi += 1
hi -= 1
```

Now by using `+=` or `-=` like above, the variable must already be defined as these operators will directly change the value of the variable. Basically, they are like this:

```
hi += 1 # is the same as hi = hi + 1
hi -= 1 # is the same as hi = hi - 1
```

So in conclusion, they are different as:

- `==` is a comparison operator: returns `True` is the two items are equal, returns `False` if not, throws error if used to assign variable before definition and if the two items are not compatible
- `=` is an assignment operator: will assign values like strings or numbers to variables. Can be used in forms like `+=` when variable's value is a number and is already defined.

The only way they can be used the same time is that they can be used in strings:

```
"hi = hello"
"2 == 3 probably returns False don't you think?"
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is `=` is an assignment operator, `==` is a comparison operator.  And you are wrong in saying that `==` can be used in any situation when `=` works. For example if I wanted to create the variable `my_string` and set it equal to `"something"` I would use the `=` operator.

```
my_string = "something"
```

I am **assigning** the variable to an object using that operator.

If I want to compare two strings (or other data types) like this:

```
if "something" == "nothing":
    #perform a function
```

I am **comparing** the two strings.

However if I try to **assign** a variable with the `==` operator for the initial assignment of the variable it will not work. If it is already assigned it will work but it will not do what you expect. For example:

```
my_string == "something"
```

Will raise an error a Name Error.

Likewise if you try to **compare** two strings (or other data types) with the `=` operator like this:

```
if "something" = "nothing":
    #perform a function
```

This will raise a Syntax Error.

I hope this helps you understand this concept. Happy programming!

Comment: `my_string == "something"` does *not* throw an error.  Have you tested that?

Comment: In what code?  I haven't found anything for which it does.

Comment: If you try to assign `my_string == "something"` as the initial assignment of `my_string`. Try typing `my_string == "something"` into a fresh python shell.

Comment: Some typos: `asigning`; `through you an error` -> `throw you an error`. Although in Python we normally say that exceptions are raised rather than thrown, but I guess that's just a minor point. But you might like to mention that it raises a `NameError`, and why it does that.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I do agree with PM2Ring.  What the error is, and why the error occurs is not clear.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for the input, and the spelling correction. It is tough to catch those mistakes sometimes even after looking over what you wrote. :)

Comment: Much better! But maybe you could say: If you haven't assigned anything to `my_string` then `my_string == "something"` will raise a NameError because there isn't anything named `my_string` yet. Or something. :)

Answer (score 2):

`=` is *assignment* operator, it is used to *assign* something to a variable:

```
A = 67 #this is called assignment. With this, A has a value of 67
```

`==` is *comparison* operator, it is used to *compare* an item to another item to see if they are equal. It results in *true* or *false*

```
A == 65 #Is A equal to 65? This does NOT assign A to 65. If A was previously assigned as 67, it still retains its 67 value
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `name = value` is *telling* Python that `name` is now equal to `value`.  `name == value`, on the other hand, is *asking* Python if `name` is equal to `value`.  There are places where you can't *tell* Python what `name` is equal to, but you *can* ask.  For example, if you want to print it:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> print x = 4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print x = 4
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That is because we are printing something, but `x = 4` has no value.  It is `x` that has the value, so we want to know if `x` is equal to `4`; we don't want to tell Python that it is.  In that case, you need double `=`:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> print x == 4
True
```

In any place that you can use `=`, you can use `==`; but it will have a different meaning.  For example:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> print x
4
>>> x == 4
True
```

`x = 4` tells Python that `x` is equal to `4`.  Nothing else is displayed because it is just a command.  `x == 4` on the other hand is *asking* if `x` is equal to `4`.  When we ask a question, the Python shell will tell us the answer, so it prints `True`.

Answer (score 1):

As MarkyPython already said. Assignment means you use the `=` to assign the value on the right side to a variable `a` on the left side.  `a=10` means that `a` is equal to `10` from here on.

The expression `a==10` tests if a variable `a` is equal to 10. The outcome of such a test is a Boolean (True or False). Such tests are typically used in `if...then` decisions.

```
a=10            # a is assigned the value of 10, and per duck-typing the type integer
print a         # --> 10
print type(a)   # --> int

print a==10     # --> True 
print a==11     # --> False

if a==10:            # if the condition is True
    do something
else: 
    do something else
```