# While loop in python keeps looping forever

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I learned python years ago and I am just trying to re-learn it now. I'm trying to make a basic program that asks name and age, and I have a while loop to try and make sure that the person actually puts in the correct numbers to confirm their name, but it just keeps looping over and over.

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Are you sure your name is",name,"? Type 1 for YES or  2 for NO.")
sure = int(input())
while(sure != 1 or 2):
    sure == input("Please type 1 for yes or 2 for NO.")
```

Comment: You wrote `==` instead of `=`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857752/what-do-the-symbol-and-mean-in-python

Comment: Also, `sure != 1 or 2` is always true. You may want something like `sure not in (1, 2)`

Comment: The condition is actually parsed like this: `sure != 1` OR `2`. The `2` evaluates to True always, so you have (MaybeTrue OR True), which is always True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems that can be fix to make your code work.

1. `sure` captures the `input` as an `int` but only the first time.

   **The fix:** Move `int()` into the `while` loop declaration, or even better compare `sure` to a string by quoting `'1'` and `'2'` as `input` will return a string.
2. `or '2'` is incorrect as `sure` is never compared to `'2'`. You were probably thinking:

   ```
   sure != '1' or sure != '2' #'or' would not work in this scenario
   ```

   or

   ```
   sure != '1' and sure != '2'
   ```

   However, this could more simply be written as `sure not in ('1','2')`.

   **The fix:** replace `!= '1' or '2'` declaration with: `not in ('1','2')`
3. In the loop `sure == input` is a comparison and not an assignment.

   **The fix:** replace `sure == input` with: `sure = input`

The fixed code should look like the following:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Are you sure your name is",name,"? Type 1 for YES or  2 for NO.")
sure = input()
while(sure not in ('1','2')):
    sure = input("Please type 1 for yes or 2 for NO.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that 'sure' it's always !=1 or 2, try with 'and'