# Why would the if staments need to be == to 0. Im a beginner

Tags: python

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if year & 4 ==0:
        return True
    if year % 100 ==0:
        return False
    if year % 400 ==0:
        return True

    return leap

year = int(input())
```

Comment: Do you know what `%` does?

Comment: Input a number, if the number divided by 100 or 400 leaves no remainder, it will equal 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the symbol "=" and "==" mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857752/what-do-the-symbol-and-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `=` and `==` do different things:

- `=` assigns *x* to *y*
- `==` checks if two items are equal (True or False)

In your if statement, you are checking two items:

```
if year % 4 == 0:
    return True
```

So you are checking whether the remainder when dividing `year` by 4 is equal to 0 so you need `==`.